# encounter an ampty graph while trying to plot the LSTM prediction

Tags: python-3.x

I want to plot the LSTM graph prediction, here is the code:

```
y_pred_FF = model_LSTM.predict(X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0],1))

plt.plot(y_test, "b-+", label='Ground truth', color = "red")
plt.plot(y_pred_FF, "b-", label='Internet Traffic prediction', color = "blue")
plt.legend()
plt.ylim(4,18)
plt.xlim(0, 200)
plt.xlabel('Time instannces', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Activity', fontsize=16)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

It does not show any error but the graph is empty as it shown in the attached figure.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWSYX.png)

Comment: Assuming there are values in `y_test` and `y_pred_FF` (you shall print them out to verify), the most likely cause is that you set `plt.ylim(4, 18)`. Your y value might be outside that range. Comment out that line and run your code again. See if the graph shows up.